# Writing xpath for selenium tests and difference between them

Tags: java, facebook, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have written xpath for "Sign Up" button of facebook as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_7']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_7']")).click();//there is a dot (.) before //
```

Both of them are working well. What's the difference between two xpath mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//` finds all elements matching `*[@id='u_0_7']` in the entire document.

`.//` finds all elements matching `*[@id='u_0_7']` in the current context.

In your example, there is no difference, since `driver.findElement(By)` has global context.

But you can call `findElement(By)` on a `WebElement`, for example

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table")).findElement(By.xpath("//ul"));
```

would find all `<ul>`s in the entire document, clearly not intended. But using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table")).findElement(By.xpath(".//ul"));
```

would find all `<ul>`s that are children of the first found `<table>`, like it was intended.

Comment: Worth mentioning it is not advised to use * This ensures search happens against all the nodes. Instead we can specify the exact type of object for ex in your case button

Comment: Even better: `By.xpath("id(u_0__7)"`, or `By.id("u_0_7")`

Comment: I think it's better to use id as By.id("u_0_7")